# a javascript message from a servlet

Tags: javascript

how could i display a javascript message from a servlet.
I am searching examples

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's a bit confusing: servlet is a server-side technology. JavaScript is working at the client-side (or you have a JS server?). You probably want to use AJAX to display a result of a servlet. I suggest you trying out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

You can check out this question as well on SO: [How to learn AJAX using jQuery in a Java web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773508/how-to-learn-ajax-using-jquery-in-a-java-web-app)

Comment: it's really nothing, but pls accept the answer if it helped :)